# Put a Custom Component on The Central Repository

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder, maven-central

If I understand correctly, one can import custom components into SceneBuilder straight from The Central Repository. How can I do that?

### What I *do* know

I know that if I click *the little cog* and then *JAR/FXML Manager*, I can add Custom Components.[image: JAR/FXML Manager]

Then I've figured out so far that if I click *Search repositories* and type in the GroupId or ArtifactId, it will search for custom components on The Central Repository (right?)
[image: Search repositories]

If I'm using IntelliJ, am a Maven Noob, and I've got a custom component, how do I get said component on to the Central Repository so that it's easily shareable?

Comment: This depends no what your objective is.  Maven is useful for developers to share around common libraries, but not end users.  So my counter to this question is, to what end do you plan on "sharing" your component?  Are you developing this for others to consume (and do you plan on maintaining it)?  Or is this more for local development purposes?

Comment: The custom control will be part of an application I'm developing for another company. So, I'm just trying to make it easy to use for any developers that use it in the future.